# How to save socket clients data into array and use it later on

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I am receiving data from different GPS devices in my TCP socket server. Each device has a unique id that is coming on with its response. All I want is whenever the new device connects with my server, I want to query my database first and then save that data into an array along with that socket data. So if that device sends data again, I don't need to query my database again. This is what I have tried so far

```js
const Net = require('net');
var socketarray = [];
const server = new Net.Server();
const HOST = "IP";
const PORT = 8888;
var car_id;
var car_no;
var car_username;

server.listen(PORT, HOST);
  server.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('A new connection has been established.');

    socket.on('data', function(data) {
      var server_data = data.toString();
      var car_details = server_data.split(',').filter(str => str != "");
      var car_id = car_details[0];
      var find_string = socketarray.findIndex(x => x.car_id == car_id);
      if (find_string === -1) {
        getCarDetails(car_id, function(car_details) {
          var length = socketarray.push({
            "car_id": "" + car_id,
            "car_no": car_details.car_no,
            "car_username": car_details.username,
          });
  
          car_id = car_id;
          car_no = car_details.car_no;
          car_username = car_details.username;
        });
        index = length - 1;
      } else {
        index = find_string;
        car_id = socketarray[find_string].car_id;
        car_no = socketarray[find_string].car_no;
        car_username = socketarray[find_string].car_username;
      }
    });
  
    socket.on('end', function() {
      console.log('Closing connection with the client');
    });
  
    socket.on('error', function(err) {
      console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
    });
});


function getCarDetails(car_id,callback) {
  console.log("db called");
  db.getConnection((err, connection) => {
    if(err){
      console.log("error is" + err);
      //throw err;
      return;
    }
    console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
    let selectQuery = 'SELECT * FROM ?? WHERE ?? = ?';
    let query = mysql.format(selectQuery, ["car", "id", car_id]);
    // query = SELECT * FROM `todo` where `user` = 'shahid'
    connection.query(query, (err, data) => {
      connection.release();
      if(err) {
        console.error(err);
        //throw err;
        return;
      }
      // rows fetch
      if(data.length > 0){
        return callback(data[0]);
      } else{
        return callback(false);
      }
   });
  });
}
```

I am using these variables later in my program and also modifying the array by using `index` variables like this e.g `socketarray[index].car_username = "bello"`. But somehow I am having issues like data got mixed up. Since I am pushing into DB at the end but the issue is sometimes some other car data get inserted into some other car data in MySQL.
Am I doing something wrong in the program? I am having difficulties tracking the exact issue of where on what position arrays got mixed up.

Comment: Why are you using global variables to store `car_id`, `car_no`, `car_details`. This could cause issues when multiple sockets connect to your application. You should put those variables inside the socket context.

Comment: @thchp you mean inside this function `server.on('connection', function(socket) {});`

Comment: @thchp and I have 500 devices sending data to my server every 5 second. so will that variables causing this issue? should I define those inside  here
server.on('connection', function(socket) {});

Comment: it depends on what you do with this variable. But every device will update it every 5 seconds

Comment: @thchp I am later on using based on these variables using different things.